# Turn off automatic language switch in Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

I have built multilingual site on Joomla 2.5. 
Everything by manuals and working perfectly.
However I would like to turn off automatic language switching.
Now if user with specific language come to site he is redirected to page with appropriate language.
I would like to avoid it, and let user choose language by himself.
Thank you for attention.